# Erro de socket em C recv(), send() // SERVER [ENCERRADA]

Tags: c, linux, socket

Sou novato em c e na área de redes, fui criar um código em c para colocar em prática a teoria, contudo, após bindar e criar o socket do connect, qualquer função como recv() ou send() me retorna -1 [erro]. Por vezes também, só de colocar um printf() ou alterar qualquer pequena coisa no código eu recebo um erro de conexão no lado cliente. Para simular um cliente estou utilizando o netcat 7.8. Se houver possibilidade de alguém me explicar o porque deste erro serei grato. Se houver sugestões de melhorias no código e tudo mais por favor, não hesitem em falar! Grato.

Eis o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\niniciando ...\n");
    int server, conecta, client,x;
    struct sockaddr_in endereco_servidor;
    struct sockaddr_in endereco_cliente;

    server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    endereco_servidor.sin_family = AF_INET;
    endereco_servidor.sin_port = htons(30000);
    endereco_servidor.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.176");

    bind(server, (struct sockaddr *)&endereco_servidor, sizeof endereco_servidor);
    x = listen(server, 1);
    while(1==1)
    {
        printf("\nENtROU WHILE\n");
        client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr *)&endereco_cliente, sizeof endereco_cliente);  
        x = send(client, "Ola", 100, 0);
        printf("%i", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**O principal problema é o seguinte:**

Na chamada a `accept` você está passando o terceiro argumento incorretamente.
Esse terceiro argumento deverá ser o endereço de memória da variável que guardará o tamanho da struct relativa ao cliente.
Isso é devido ao fato desta função poder modificá-la.

Logo, você pode declarar uma nova variável para isso antes:

```
int size_endereco_cliente = sizeof(endereco_cliente);
```

E na chamada a `accept` passar o seu ponteiro, desta forma:

```
client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr *) &endereco_cliente, &size_endereco_cliente);
```

No mais, se você não tiver interesse em saber as informações do cliente, é possível simplesmente passar `NULL` como segundo e terceiros argumentos:

```
client = accept(server, NULL, NULL);
```

É uma alternativa.

**Melhorias:**

Há um defeito no envio do "Ola" para o cliente. Executando do jeito que está você vai perceber que o cliente receberá uns caracteres estranhos logo depois da mensagem. Isso é porque há uma necessidade de ajustar o terceiro argumento de `send` para o tamanho correto da mensagem que está no segundo argumento. E, neste caso, esse tamanho não é 100.

Recomendo usar uma variável para guardar a mensagem e medi-la com `strlen()` no momento do envio.

**Dica:** Você está usando o IP do computador na LAN como endereço para o servidor, talvez ele não seja estático. Nesse caso, recomendo usar 127.0.0.1 para fazer os testes se forem apenas no seu computador.

**Referências:**

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/accept-system-call

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html

https://linux.die.net/man/2/send

Comment: Na parte em que utilizo (struct sockaddr *)&endereco_cliente, o que este ponteiro significa? Ah, e obrigado pela resposta e dicas bem claras, foram de grande ajuda!